# Moment of Inertia of a Solid Sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, moment-of-inertia

I just seen the following derivation of I for a solid sphere about an axis through the center of the sphere:

$$I= \int V\hat{r}^2dm
=\int_0^\pi\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{R}_0\rho(r\sin\phi)^2r^2\sin\phi\,drd\theta d\phi
=\frac{2\pi\rho}{5}R^5\int^\pi_0\sin^3(\phi) d\phi $$

Where $\hat{r} = r\sin\phi$ is defined as the distance of any point from the axis. My question is, why is $r\sin\phi$ squared and why is the bounds on $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$?

Comment: Are you actually asking why $\hat r$ is squared? If it is squared then clearly $r\sin\phi$ is squared.

Comment: Are you familiar with spherical coordinates?

Comment: Why do you have a $V$ in there?

Comment: Does your book really use $\phi$ for the polar angle and $\theta$ for the azimuthal one? This is backwards from what I am used to seeing.

Comment: @G.Smith My book uses them the other way around as well, this is a proof I actually found online, sorry! I am asking why $\hat{r} $ is squared, and the V is meant to be for volume I think, but I couldn't decode this proof well enough.

Comment: @AaronStevens I am!

Comment: *I am asking why $\hat r$ is squared.* To understand that, you need to go back and look at how angular momentum is related to angular velocity, and thus why the moment of inertia is defined the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point-particle has the [moment-of-inertia](https://www.allthatmatters.academy/courses/rotation-2/lessons/moment-of-inertia/) $I=m \hat r^2$, where $m$ is the particle's mass and $\hat r$ the distance from the rotational axis.

Your integral sums up all the values of $I$ for each of the infinitely many point-particles that the sphere consists of. Since $\hat r=r\sin(\phi)$, then when plugged into the formula for $I$ you get it squared: $\hat r^2=(r\sin(\phi))^2$.

Regarding the integration limits for this sphere parameterization, think of it like this:

- We integrate over the parameter $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, to draw a full circle.
- Then we "flip" that circle over in order to form / sweep out a sphere (a spherical shell). If you have a circle, you only have to rotate it (about an axis through the circle centre and parallel to a tangent) half a round in order to have swept through a spherical space. So, we only integrate from $0$ to $\pi$, which is half a round.
- Finally, the parameter $r$ takes care of the radius, and by integrating from $0$ to $R$, we "fill out" the sphere up to the radius $R$.

Comment: Thank you! This answers everything I needed!

Answer (score 0):

They are using spherical coordinates to do the integral, not cylindrical ones. The notation is a bit confusing as they use the same letter r, to denote distance from origin in $r$ and to denote distance from the rotation axis in  $\hat{r}$. The distance from the rotation axis is $rsin\phi$, which is squared. The other term ($r^2sin\phi$) is the Jacobian.